# How to count any column's cells count in excel with robotframework

Tags: robotframework

this is the excel:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpLUg.png)

I want to get the first column's cell count, I use excellibrary, but the `Get Row Count` method doesn't suite my case, it get the max row in excel,any solution?

my code as below(i use ride):

```
Open Excel | D:\\try.xls
${a} | Get Column Count | Sheet1
```

the result is 4, but i want to get 3

Answer (score 0):

The excellibrary uses internally a python lib for working with Excel files - xlrd; the keyword `Get Column Count` is actually returning the property `ncols` of a `Sheet` object in it, [the documentation of which says](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.sheet.Sheet.ncols):

> Nominal number of columns in sheet. It is one more than the maximum column index found, ignoring trailing empty cells.

So it will always return one more than the actual used - just subtract the extra one.